# Load a universal stylesheet

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, directory

How do I load the same files from the home/?

example : my index loads fine from css/stylesheet but when i move it to a folder (say page 2), how do i still load that stylesheet from the home css/stylesheet location without having to put the whole link?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your CSS directory is in your web root, instead of

```
css/stylesheet.css
```

Use

```
/css/stylesheet.css
```

That first `/` basically means "starting from the web root". This way you do not have to use a full URL to refer to your stylesheet.